# Updating objects from REST API calls - struct merge?

Tags: go

I have a JSON REST API accepting sparse updates, but the pattern I've come up with seems exceptionally verbose. Am I going about this the wrong way?

(Assume this is using a data store with no sparse update support built in.)

```
func choose(a, b *string) *string {
    if a != nil {
        return a
    }
    return b
}

type Model {
    Id     *string `json:"id"`
    Field1 *string `json:"field1"`
    Field2 *string `json:"field2"`
    Field3 *string `json:"field3"`
    ...
}

func (m1 Model) Update(m2 Model) (m3 Model) {
    m3.Id = choose(m2.Id, m1.Id)
    m3.Field1 = choose(m2.Field1, m1.Field1)
    m3.Field2 = choose(m2.Field2, m1.Field2)
    m3.Field3 = choose(m2.Field3, m1.Field3)
    ...
    return
}

func UpdateController(input Model) error {
    previous, _ := store.Get(*input.Id)
    updated := previous.Update(input)
    return store.Put(updated)
}
```

Ideally I'd be able to write `UpdateController` like this instead:

```
func UpdateController(input Model) {
    previous, _ := store.Get(*input.Id)
    updated, _ := structs.Update(previous, input)
    return store.Put(updated)
}
```

(Error-handling elided for clarity.)

Comment: You can achieve this with reflection, but the verbose way will give you much better performance. If you want an example on how to do this with reflection I can write a simplified example.

Comment: BTW you can also use code generation to automatically generate explicit merging functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, if you are open to using reflection, the problem becomes fairly simple:

http://play.golang.org/p/dc-OnO1cZ4

```
func (m1 Model) Update(m2 Model) (m3 Model) {
    old := reflect.ValueOf(m1)
    new := reflect.ValueOf(m2)
    final := reflect.ValueOf(&m3).Elem()
    for i := 0; i < old.NumField(); i++ {
        if !new.Field(i).IsNil()  {
           final.Field(i).Set(new.Field(i))
        } else {
           final.Field(i).Set(old.Field(i))
        }      
    }
    return
}
```

The reason we do `reflect.ValueOf(&m3).Elem()` is that v3 needs to be settable, see http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection

But basically, by using reflection, we can loop through the struct fields, see if the updated one is nil, and if so, we use the old value.

Comment: Thanks. I figured that would be the way to go, but I haven't actually done any reflection code in Go yet. It's much simpler than I expected!

Answer (score 4):

Another option, if you don't want to use reflection, is to retrieve the object from the database and pass it's address to the JSON decoder. Only the fields defined in the JSON of the update method will be updated. Then you can use a normal method to save the changes to the database. Here's a sample code using gin and gorm.

```
func TodoUpdate(c *gin.Context) {
    var todo Todo
    todoId := c.Param("todoId")
    DB.First(&todo, todoId)
    if err := json.NewDecoder(c.Request.Body).Decode(&todo); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Update error. Error:", err.Error())
    }
    DB.Save(&todo)
}
```

So, for example, if you have `{"ID":1,"name":"Do stuff","completed":false}` in your database, and send something like `{"completed":true}` to your update method (`/todos/1`, where 1 is `todoId`) you'll end up with this: `{"ID":1,"name":"Do stuff","completed":true}`.

Answer (score 2):

### Use reflection

You can update the `Model` using reflection, and [the `reflect` package](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/).

The following function updates the old `Model` in-place:

```
func (old *Model) MergeInPlace(new Model) {
    for ii := 0; ii < reflect.TypeOf(old).Elem().NumField(); ii++ {
        if x := reflect.ValueOf(&new).Elem().Field(ii); !x.IsNil() {
            reflect.ValueOf(old).Elem().Field(ii).Set(x)
        }
    }
}
```

You would call this method by saying `x.MergeInPlace(y)`, where `x` and `y` are `Model`s. `x` will be modified after you call this function.

### Sample output

"Merging" the following,

```
{  
   "id":"1",
   "field1":"one",
   "field2":"two",
   "field3":"three"
}
{  
   "id":"1",
   "field3":"THREE"
}
```

yields:

```
{  
   "id":"1",
   "field1":"one",
   "field2":"two",
   "field3":"THREE"
}
```

That is, it overwrites all values present in the new struct in the old one, ignoring values that are "undefined".

Obviously, you can Marshal (or not) as you please.

### Complete program

[See a complete, working example at the Go Playground.](http://play.golang.org/p/_l9srHDHKo)

The normal caveats (check returned errors in production!) apply.

Comment: This is good and just what I was looking for too, but only works if your struct types are pointers because the `IsNil()` call. If, for example, `Field1 *string` was `Field string` it'd panic. So you'll need to see if the field is a pointer first (`reflect.Ptr`) before calling `IsNil()` else check for a Zero value. See updated: https://play.golang.org/p/cg9pQrfVOl

Comment: I forgot to note that this also assumes you want to merge in empty values. Look at Field3 for example. Since it is not set on the new struct, it will get its empty string value which will replace the value in the old struct. So this merge/update assumes you want to be able to remove values. If not, then you may wish to work with nil values or write in some sort of exception.

Comment: For completeness, you can check `if x.String() != ""` where the `.Set()` call is made. `String()` is special in that it won't panic so you can easily choose to skip the field and keep the old original value. See field 3 now: https://play.golang.org/p/dUgelcIjJ2